# Should I use a shorter accessory belt?

Tags: ac, jeep, belt, grand-cherokee

I've had the A/C discharged on an older truck (2001 Grand Cherokee 4.7L v8), and soon I plan to remove the entire A/C system, specifically, the compressor.

1. Is there anything that I should be concerned about in doing so (defrost and cabin cooling are not a concern).
2. After removing it, is there any reason for me not to just use a shorter belt?  It will clear everything without issue.  The alternative being to make a bracket and put a pulley in place of the compressor pulley.

Comment: This really depends on the serpentine system. If you could post your vehicle information we could most likely be able to give you an educated answer.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Updated.  I didn't include specific vehicle details initially because I'm looking for more general "what concerns should I be aware of" feedback.

Comment: If your vehicle was available without air conditioning then there will be a stock belt that discards the A/C compressor for its path. You might have to  remove the compressor and its housing in order to clear a path. Send it to me. I'm looking for one to pressurize my nerf bars (as a compressed air tank) in case of a flat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the routing it may work with a shorter belt. But it may not have enough tension to drive the water pump without slipping. Dorman may make an A/C delete pulley/bracket. Which would keep the original belt routing and length.

[image]

Comment: If tension is the only issue (which was a concern of mine), then I will make a bracket and pulley for it, or possibly see if I can rework the tensioner.  Thanks :)

Comment: One question, aren't engine pulley systems usually designed in two ways, with and without a compressor, both of which are identical, but latter simply lacks a compressor pulley and comes with a shorter belt? Or do all Cherookees come with an A/C?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing From what I can tell the 4.7 only comes with the A/C option on the grand cherokee. If it was a 4.0 though the belt routing/length is different between A/C/Non-A/C

Comment: After looking more closely in person, I've realized that while it should work without the pulley (including the water pump), it will put the belt running dangerously close to itself in one spot.  In the interest of not doing stupid things, I'm going to use a compressor delete pulley (or make one) for the time being.  TY all.